# Firebase url to json version of the database data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a firebase database and added some data to the database.

It has given me a url like this:

```
https://my-app-name.firebaseio.com/
```

My question is...does firebase provide a url to a json version of my database data if so what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you add data into your Firebase Realtime database, each node becomes a `JSON` particular version of your database. Let's say you have a node named `users`, your URL will be:

```
https://my-app-name.firebaseio.com/users/
```

To download the JSON file, simply go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), choose your project, select your database, click the `users` node and download the `JSON` file from the right side, using `Export JOSN` option.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if https://my-app-name.firebaseio.com/users.json was a thing

Answer (score 2):

You *can* get the json of any node by simply going to this url:

```
https://[my-app-name].firebaseio.com/[path].json
```

Just replace [my-app-name] with the name of your realtime firebase app name, and path with the json node you want to see.

Source: [Firebase Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database)

If you open in a browser you will just see the json minimized. If you add a json viewer Chrome extension such as [DJSON. JSON Viewer & Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djson-json-viewer-formatt/chaeijjekipecdajnijdldjjipaegdjc/related?hl=en-US), it will be pretty.

[image: DJSON. JSON Viewer & Formatter]

Additionally, you can then copy/paste that into [Json Grid](https://jsongrid.com/json-grid) to see even a better representation that organizes tables:

[image: Json Grid]